# How to set up websocket server listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket, listener

I am trying to make a websocket client in a chrome extension that will listen for open websocket servers. Once one is open, it will connect and perform its task. How do I set it so that the client will start listening right after disconnection?

This is the code I have to connect, but I have no idea how to make it into a listener.

```
function connect(host) {
    var ws = new WebSocket(host);

    ws.onopen = function () {
        alert('connected');
        connection = true;
    };

ws.onmessage = function (evt, tab) {  
    if(evt.data == "connect"){
        rpwd = 'hello ws';
        ports[curTabID].postMessage({text: rpwd});
}
};

ws.onclose = function () {
    alert('socket closed');
    connection = false;
    webConnect('ws://localhost:8080');
};
};
```

Comment: What you have in the browser us just a client, it cannot act as a server.

Comment: I know this is much later but the blog post was the next month after, way back in Aug '15:  http://blog.revathskumar.com/2015/08/websockets-simple-client-and-server.html  (it also requires Node.js, like socket.io)

Comment: Basically, the browser's websockets can only listen to a port, but you can run Javascript in Node.js on the same machine that puts up a server on the same port, takes in connections from elsewhere, and serves as the intermediary between the browser and outside clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't easily do it.

1) Standard API, `WebSocket`, is only a client, nothing you can do about that. The browser is not supposed to be a server.

2) Extensions are supposed to augment the browser functionality, so `chrome` APIs can possibly help. Unfortunately, in case of *extensions* the answer is still no.

3) For Chrome *apps*, however, it *is* possible. There is a [`chrome.sockets.tcpServer` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer), but of course no bundled server implementations. You would have to either implement a web+ws server yourself, or use one of the existing solutions like [this one](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/websocket-server).

---

That aside, are you sure you *really want a WS server?* You said it's to "listen for open servers" - how would servers make their presence known? Wouldn't it be more logical to just poll them periodically to see if they are open?

Comment: How would you go about doing that in the chrome background.js?

Comment: Did you read my answer? And please answer the questions I had first.

Comment: Did you read my question? The extension is supposed to be the client, and it needs to check for open servers. You stated my question in your answer, and I asked how I would go about doing that. I'm still new to programming and would like to know the method to poll for webservers without getting the extension stuck in a loop.

Comment: Well, you used the word "listen", which has a specific meaning in client-server context. You can't open a port to listen in an extension - you can only initiate a connection yourself. To poll without a loop, use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a browser has any way of listening for connections using WebSockets.  Everything I have read including the documentation for socket.io point to node.js being the only JavaScript way of listening, or providing server sockets.